# I have created multiselect Product attribute but it is not visible on frontend as a filter on Product Listing Page

Tags: magento2, php

**Check this code.**

```
        [
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'type' => 'text',
            'sort_order' => 210,
            'label' => 'Collection',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'searchable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'used_for_promo_rules' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'apply_to' => implode(',', [Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL]),
            'option' => [
                'value' => [
                    'option_1' => ['Option 1'],
                    'option_2' => ['Option 2'],
                    'option_3' => ['Option 3']
                ],
                'order' => [
                    'option_1' => 1,
                    'option_2' => 2,
                    'option_3' => 3
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have fixed it, by my self.
> **'type' => 'varchar'** is a important thing for multiselect product attribute.

```
        [
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Collection',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\CollectionOptions',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'sort_order' => 210,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'used_for_promo_rules' => true,
            'apply_to' => implode(',', [Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL]),
            'option' => [
                'values' => [
                    'Option 1',
                    'Option 2',
                    'Option 3'
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

> **namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Source;**

```
class CollectionOptions extends AbstractSource
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {

            $this->_options = [
               ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Option 1')],
               ['value' => 2, 'label' => __('Option 2')],
               ['value' => 3, 'label' => __('Option 3')],
            ];

        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|string $value
     * @return array|bool|mixed|string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $isMultiple = false;
        if (strpos($value, ',')) {
            $isMultiple = true;
            $value = explode(',', $value);
        }

        $options = $this->getAllOptions();

        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $value = [$value];
        }
        $optionsText = [];
        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if (in_array($item['value'], $value)) {
                $optionsText[] = $item['label'];
            }
        }

        if ($isMultiple) {
            return $optionsText;
        } elseif ($optionsText) {
            return $optionsText[0];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show this attribute on PLP filter

Set "**Use In Layered Navigation**" to **YES** in backend product attribute edit Storefront Properties section.

[source](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/navigation-layered-filterable-attributes.html)

Comment: Thanks your for your reply, but it is not working.

Comment: @PratikMehta - Please check whether have you set this attribute value to different products which are currently presented in that category.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Stores -> Product (under Attributes)** Select the attribute and go to '**StoreFront Properties**' and change the necessary changes.

*Hope it will work.*

[image: Refer the scrrenshots]

Comment: Thanks your for your reply, but it is not working.

Comment: @PratikMehta - Please check whether have you assigned this attribute to the products which are currently presented in that category. If possible please provide us the screenshots.